# MySQL: Port issues on an domain network setup

Tags: windows, firewall, mysql, port

I am looking for options to have a MySQL server on corporate environment where opening a port in the Windows Firewall is quite difficult (a lot of red tape). At this point I am not looking to have a lot of users (5-6) and we should be able to install MySQL in all workstations without problem. All users have access to share drive that we can use to write the data (at this stage the database are quite small; only a few MBs of information). I guess my question is would a setup like this is possible? Have a central location for the MySQL data and install MySQL in all workstations. I saw some information about MySQL replication but it seems what I need is a little bit different.

Comment: If there's a business need, put together a business case and pass it up the chain. Include budget to contract the DB skills. When it comes to databases, do them right the first time, or suffer. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63832/two-mysql-server-accessing-same-database-over-nfs

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the startup parameters for the MySQL server, there would be nothing stopping you from changing the default port to something that is accessible through the firewalls.

However, you should be seriously asking yourself whether the existing security may be there for a reason. If nothing else, you could easily end up out of a job (or worse in some regulated industries) as this could be seen as bypassing corporate security. Certainly I would take a very dim view of this in my role.

You should also be asking how supportable that arrangement might be. What happens when you leave, will anyone be able to work out how things work or why?

There is a lot more to IT than just bulling something into existence without regard to consequences.